# Reputation graph: Could you add an option to see it in the old cumulative style?

Tags: feature-request, design, profile-page, reputation-tab

Reputation graph: Could you add an option to see it in the old cumulative style?

I would like to present this suggestion: current plot in the Reputation tab shows a plot like this one:
[image: current reputation plot]

But sometimes when I have connection issues the page send me to this other cumulative plot (like it was previously a few years), which I found more useful (to keep myself outside the range where I could lose the privilege of creating chats):

[image: cumulative reputation plot]

I know maybe it is kind of stupid suggestion, but also since I don't know how to reach the cumulative plot in purpose (neither why sometimes I reach it accidentally), and maybe it is just adding a few lines of code, I hope you could add an option to see the plot in both alternatives.

Comment: This graph already exists on your network profile page, see for instance [here](https://stackexchange.com/users/21140336/joako?tab=reputation). (This link is for the OP - to get there for any user, go to their MSE profile, click the "Profiles" dropdown at top right, click "Network Profile", then go to the "Reputation" section.)

Comment: Just a note that the "Profiles" dropdown isn't one of the icons on the RHS of the very top of your page, but is a little bit down from there, below the "Mathematics" banner, and actually says the word "Profiles" on it. It took me a while to find it.

Comment: @KReiser Thanks for the link, but if it already, Does it means is even simpler to make my request? honestly the current plot, at least for me, means nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Last I read (somewhere on meta.stackexchange), there's some minimum number of pixels that have to be available on your display in order for the cumulative rep chart to be shown. I guess this makes sense to the UX designers, but for me the effect was that sometimes I'd see it and sometimes I wouldn't. Frustrating.

Anyways, my recommendation is to be on the not-mobile version, go to your math.stackexchange user page, pick your 'Activity' tab, and make your browser window as wide as possible. You should be able to see it then. (At least I do. I've seen that bar chart before, but I don't remember how. But it's the cumulative one that displays for me right now.)

Here are my results, at two slightly different browser widths:

Narrower:

[image]

Wider:

[image]

It even updates dynamically - have fun watching it blink in and out of existence as you resize your browser window!

Comment: Here's one place on Meta SE where this was reported: [bad_coder](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/665544/bad-coder)'s [answer to "New responsive Activity page"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372868).